# Convert mm/yyyy to mmyy in PHP

Tags: php, date

My apologies if this is repetitive but I did search for an answer to no avail.

I have a date. It's an object, which I've converted to a string:

```
$exp = (string)$date;
```

This variable displays as: `10/2013`

But when I try to convert the mm/yyyy format to mmyy, using this code:

```
$ex = date($exp);
$e = date('m Y',$ex);
```

...not only do I get the following error notice:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...
```

...but my date also gets changed to: `1269` (as in December 1969 [huh?])

What am I doing wrong?

-bob

Comment: What sort of object is the original `$date`?  A [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/DateTime) or an [`int-time()`](http://ca.php.net/time) perhaps?  1969 is the min date, a side effect of the bad-parse.

Comment: What kind of object? A `DateTime` object by chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$date = substr_replace($date,' ',2,3);
```

dunno why do you need such a strange format though

Comment: that's the way my credit card processor wants it...btw, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function accepts a Unix timestamp as its second parameter. If it doesn't recognize it as a number, it could be treated as `0` (which indicates the epoch, Dec 31, 1969). To create a timestamp, I think you meant

```
$ex = strtotime($exp);
```

instead of

```
$ex = date($exp);
```

But even then, '10/2013' is not an accepted date format by `strtotime()`.

You could create a timestamp from your old date format like this:

```
$exp = '10/2013';
$date = explode('/', $exp);
$ex = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], 1, $date[1]);
$e = date('m Y',$ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with an incomplete date like `10/2013` you will need to do some string manipiulation to get it into `mmyy`.  If you don't actually need a timestamp output, there is no need to convert it into any sort of date object or timestamp at all.  You can merely do string manipulation.

```
list($month, $year) = explode("/", $date);
$newdate = $month . substr($year, 2);
// 1013
```

**Edit (from comments)**:
If the month is not always two digits but your output requires a 2 digit month, use:

```
$newdate = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . substr($year, 2);
```

Comment: Just in case `$month` isn't always two digits may do `$newdate = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . substr($year, 2);` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert the $date field directly:

```
 $e = date('m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

if not, then this should work

```
 $e = date('m/Y', strtotime(((string)$date)));
```

Comment: `strtotime` won't convert `mm/yyyy` properly in either of those cases

Answer (score 0):

`$exp = date("my");`

Where `my` means "month" "year".